# Share without using Google+ SDK from IOS app

Tags: ios, sdk, google-plus

I am sharing on **Facebook** and **Twitter** using Social Framework provided by apple. I cannot share on **Google+** using social framework. How I can share on **Google+** without using **Google+** SDK.

I do not want to create projects on **Google+**.

Is it possible?

**EDIT**

I have more than 8 apps for both, iPhone and android. One of my app was approved by apple but rejected by google yesterday and they suspended my app as well. Not only on google play, my google+ project is also suspended. And now my users cannot share on google+ while using my app.

I want to adopt a strategy to avoid this thin in future. I cannot even delete my suspended project.

Comment: i think it is not possible without using Google+ SDK.

Comment: Is it possible without creating app on google+?

Comment: i think creating app on google+ is compulsory because without signin can't possible sharing

Comment: on the rejected app you are using google+ sdk for google+ sharing?

Comment: That's not possible without Google+ API. You should check for the reason for which your App got suspended by Google.

Comment: I cannot even delete my suspended project?

Comment: Maybe it is possible if try to deal with webview without integrating any external SDK